# While Runing the Code Showing Error on "pCalculator.Calculate"

Tags: arcobjects, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Part 1: Define the feature class.
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass
Dim name1 As Variant
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass

Dim pCursor As ICursor
Dim pCalculator As ICalculator

' Prepare a cursor with all records.
Set pCursor = pFeatureClass.Update(Nothing, True)

' Define a calculator.
Set pCalculator = New Calculator
Set pCalculator.Cursor = pCursor

' Calculate the field values.
pCalculator.Expression = "OwnerName1"
pCalculator.Field = "OwnerName12"
pCalculator.Calculate
pMxDoc.ActivatedView.Refresh

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [code sample](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabaseUI/ICalculator_Example.htm) on the API help page you will see they use a search cursor, you are using an update cursor. Also take note on how the sample sets up the expression property when writing a text value to the field. They are enclosing the text within triple quotes you are not doing this.